# linq distinct on two columns and return as a single field

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table as below

```
Id username userid departmentname
1   abc     1234    test1
2   abc     3456    test1
3   abc     1234    test2
4   abc     3456    test2
5   def     8989    test1
```

I want to apply distinct on username and userid columns and return the two columns as a single field in linq

The required output will below

```
abc-1234
abc-3456
def-8989
```

I have tried the following

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
            [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
            public static List<string> getUserDetails(string prefixText, int count)
            {
                List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
                using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
                {
                    var distinctUsers = context.counters.Select(m => new { m.UserName, m.UserID }).Distinct().ToList();                
                    var abc = distinctUsers.Select(p => new  { DisplayText = p.UserName + "-" + p.UserID }).ToList();

                    usernames = abc.Where(r => r.DisplayText.StartsWith(prefixText)).ToList();               

                }
 return usernames;
            }
```

But I have ended up with the issue.
1) Once I have got the required results, I need to filter with the list that starts with input string(prefixtext). I have got the required results in the variable abc and could able to get the list that startswith the input string, but the error I am getting is 'Cannot implicitly convert type list anonymous to list string. How can I convert list anonymous type to list string?
2) Is the above approach better? Or is there any best way than this?

Thank you 'Ashique', I have got it as below without using group by in another line of code.

```
var distinctUsers = context.counters.Select(m => (m.UserName + "-" + m.UserID)).Distinct().ToList();
var abc = distinctUsers.AsParallel().Where(x => x.StartsWith(prefixText)).ToList();
```

By default ,the above has implemented order by too which I need. Does it order by default or should I implement something like below to order by :

```
 var distinctUsers = context.counters.Select(m => (m.UserName + "-" + m.UserID)).Distinct().OrderBy(n=>n).ToList();
```

Comment: use a "group by"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
                {
                    var distinctUsers = context.counters.Select(m => (m.UserName + "-" + m.UserID )).ToList();              
                      usernames = distinctUsers.GroupBy(g => g).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();               

                }
```

**OR**

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
                {                                 
                      usernames = context.counters.Select(m => (m.UserName + "-" + m.UserID )).GroupBy(g => g).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();               

                }
```

Comment: Can you please let me know why usernames = context.counters.Select(m => (m.UserName + "-" + m.UserID )).GroupBy(g => g).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList(); is better than usernames = context.counters.Select(m => (m.UserName + "-" + m.UserID )).Distinct().ToList();(this is including order by too)

Comment: it's all about performance.Distinct() will compare entire objects in collection on the other hand GroupBy() allows you to group object by some key.You can check this if you inspect the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
create table abc1 as
select distinct concat(username,'-',userid) as result from abc
group by username;
```